# Trouble launching program with System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()

Tags: c#, .net

What should be a *trival* matter has now gobbled up an hour of my time! >__<

I want to start an executable with a xml path as an argument.  (I've added the directory in which this program resides to my system path.)  Seems simple enough. My first approach was using the static Process.Start() method as such:

`Process.Start(@"MyExecutable.exe", "C:\\My Doc\\SomeDirectory\\MyXMLPath.xml");`

The process does start, but like half a second later it dies. So, I'm like *ooookaay*, maybe the executable doesn't like the argument I'm giving it?  Just for giggles, I created a shortcut to the executable and added the xml file path as one of it's arguments.  The program starts and runs as expected.  Not sure why this works, I decided to test my luck on the command line as well:

`C:\MyExecutable.exe "C:\My Docs\SomeDirectory\MyXMLPath.xml"`

No problem starting this way too.

Now, at this point I started grasping for straws and decided to create an instance of the Process class:

```
Process proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo.FileName = @"MyExecutable.exe";
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "C:\\My Docs\\SomeDirectory\\MyXMLPath.xml";
proc.Start();
```

Needless to say this didn't help at all. >.<

So frusterated, I decided test my luck commenting out one line:

`//proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "C:\\My Docs\\SomeDirectory\\MyXMLPath.xml";`

And the process starts. Not with its necessary arguments, but it starts. So, the question is, why is the program not accepting the path I give it when I try to launch it through the Process class?  If only it left me a message when the program died. :(

Any thoughts? Much appreciated!

Comment: Random shot in the dark: on the command-line, you're specifying `C:\MyExecutable.exe`, but in your code you're specifying just `MyExecutable.exe`.  Have you tried specifying `C:\MyExecutable.exe` in your code?  Depending on the current directory, maybe a different .exe is being picked up.

Comment: @Chris - ah, no because the executable isn't located in the root of C...I shouldn't be picking up a different executable.  There could be a very, very slim chance that I am. But I don't think it would make a difference. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem might be because of the spaces in the file path. If you think about it in how you made the DOS call you had to put quotes around the path. But the way you are calling you are not. So try adding single quotes around the path. That should take care of it. If you think about it from the standpoint of how that would look rendered as a command line then it makes more sense why you need to do that.

```
Process proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo.FileName = @"MyExecutable.exe";
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "\"C:\\My Docs\\SomeDirectory\\MyXMLPath.xml\"";
proc.Start();
```

Comment: Beat me to it.  I had to look at it several times before I thought of that.  +1 to you.

Comment: Yep, the lack of extra quotes in the arguments string may also cause it.

Comment: unfortunately the adding the single quotes didn't do it for me :(

Comment: I wasn't really sure that single quotes would work. Can you try doubling up the quotes to use double quotes?

Comment: I didn't notice your update.  :) But the updated version of the code fixes the problem.  :D  I guess since this was the first correct answer I'll mark it as such. :D Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 3):

Your arguments contain a space:

```
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "C:\\My Docs\\SomeDirectory\\MyXMLPath.xml";
```

This means that the program you're executing is receiving the following as its arguments:

- `C:\My`
- `Docs\SomeDirectory\MyXMLPath.xml`

What you need to do is wrap it in **double** quotes (not single as suggested in another answer), thusly:

```
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "\"C:\\My Docs\\SomeDirectory\\MyXMLPath.xml\"";
```

which means that the program you're executing will now receive only one argument:

- `"C:\My Docs\SomeDirectory\MyXMLPath.xml"`

Comment: yay...I can haz hero. :D

That did it. :)

Answer (score 1):

You should put in a handler for the `Exited` event of the process:

```
        Process p = new Process();
        p.Exited += new EventHandler(MyProcess_Exited);
```

and then check the `ExitCode` inside the handler:

```
    private void MyProcess_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Process p = sender as Process;

        if (p.ExitCode == someValue)......
    }
```

in the absense of any other info i would say that the privileges of the started process are insufficient to read or access the xml file.

Comment: ah, thanks...I can't believe I didn't even consider trying that. :)

Comment: alright...well, I think an exit code of -532459699 is definitely telling me something screwy is going on. :s